# How to get the value of a hash using Java

Tags: java, json, hash

I have a hash data the looks like this:

```
{"one": 500}
{"two": 600}
{"three": 700}
```

and I want to get the value for the of each hash object ex. 500, 600, 700
Can someone help me on how to achieve this dynamically without indicating the key for each hash object?

Comment: without indicating the key?? are they added to the hashtable?

Comment: Same way you would in non-Android Java...

Comment: Are you looking for [SparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hash map for this purpose,i am presenting an example as follows

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    hMap.put("one", 500);
    hMap.put("two", 600);
    hMap.put("three", 700);

    Collection c = hMap.values();
    Iterator itr = c.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<A, B> map = ...

for(B v: map.values()) { ... }
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have them in a suitable collection:

```
for (String k : map.keySet()) {
    System.err.println(String.format("%s\t%s", k, map.get(k)));
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using keySet

```
    HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    hashMap.put("one", 500);
    hashMap.put("two", 600);
    hashMap.put("three", 700);

    Set<String> keySet = hashMap.keySet();
    for (String string : keySet) {
        System.out.println(string);
        System.out.println(hashMap.get(string));
    }
```